# ADAT to USB interface

Tags: usb, conversion, interface, adat

Is there such a thing as a bridge between ADAT and USB?

It seems simple enough, and seems like it should be a very cheap device - just do some translation from the ADAT digital stream into USB.  But google is failing me.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything for USB, but there seem to be several Firewire audio interfaces that also have ADAT optical inputs.

[image]

I own a [M-Audio Profire 2626](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/ProFire2626.html) which can do 16 ADAT in/out.  Focusrite has at least [one model](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/SaffPro40) similar to the Profire with 8 ADAT in/out.

[This thread](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/38459-audio-interface-just-adat.html) on gearslutz seems to suggest a couple different Firewire interfaces.

If you have a Mac or MacBook you probably already have a Firewire interface.  If you have a PC you can [get one cheap](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_8?url=search-alias=computers&field-keywords=pci%20firewire%20card&sprefix=pci%20fire,aps,274).  If you have a PC laptop, you may be out of luck.